# Tried to Help User By Editing Their Question But They Rejected It

Tags: support

There is [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/267922/how-to-transfer-from-blender-3-xx-to-blender-2-xx) that lacked alot of details so we were exchanging comments until i realized what their problem was. So I was kind enough to help them out by doing [this edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/155745) so they could get more help and attention to their question especially that the question did get 3 downvotes for being unclear. But unfortunately the user rejected my revision. Is there no way i can escalate this to be approved by a trusted user to approve it? I think my edit was very reasonable and made the issue more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users are free to allow or reject edits to their posts. Why the user rejected yours is up to his discretion, no one other than him can tell for sure other than speculation.

The message at the top states it deviated from his original intent.
[image]

Your edits seem to focus around an error message while opening the file, but the user never mentioned finding one. From skimming over the contents his files seem to open fine, only the parenting is lost or the rig misbehaves, which seems to conflict with what your edit focused on.

That would justify the rejection.

That is a very poorly written question, with very sparse information, the user also seems to be uncooperative and offering resistance to requests for clarification.

You efforts would probably be best spent helping users who actually want to be helped.

Comment: That's a good point. Well the error does show up and quickly disappears so he might have missed it. He only mentioned it didn't work so it's pure speculation for the community to think what exactly did not work.

Comment: wow the user edited his post using curse words for his post after it was closed. he probably should get suspended or banned.

Comment: It has been removed by the moderators in the meantime. I rolled back your edit so as not to promote unwarranted fowl language so prominently here, since it seems unrelated to your question.

Comment: ok fair enough 